# ListView element

Tags: android, listview

Ребята, у меня есть список ListView. Я не могу сделать xml elment для ListView.
У меня он просто не получается. Нужно сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое тяжелое для меня это background,ибо размещения данных элементов(TextView и ImageView) у меня получается,но когда я ставлю background на элемент,то у меня он соответственно растягивается. Короче такая вот проблема. У меня вот так получается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back_list_lobby">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lock"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lock" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lobby_list_mess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="."
        android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lobby_list_items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Название"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_lobby_item"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Попробовал сделать так:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
```

Тоже не помогло.

Comment: А чем у Вас является background `back_list_lobby`? Это `shape` или картинка png?

Comment: Вы видимо даже не гуглили, так как картинку можно заюзать с помощью атрибута android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"

Comment: @АндроидАндроид а как это относится к решению задачи? Я лично сам не использую `drawableLeft/Right`, потому что это дает меньше гибкости при кастомизации. А проблема тут именно в самом `background` для контейнера и в том, что высота контейнера `wrap_content`.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov Картинка у меня png,но в разных размерах: hdpi,mdpi и т.д. Дизайн делался в Adobe Xd

Comment: @АндроидАндроид какая разница как я добавляю изображение?Здесь проблема в background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо картинки png сделай `shape`. Например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners
        android:radius="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

Радиус закругления отрегулируй по желанию. Ну и цвет тоже можно любой поставить.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду заменить FrameLayout данной конструкцией?

Comment: Нет. Создать xml файл в drawable. Вставить туда этот код. Назначить в качестве background ссылку на этот файл.

Comment: @shcherbuk и лучше установите фиксированную высоту для кнопки этой. Как вариант, согласно Material Design: 56dp, 72dp.

Comment: а с помощью каких команд задаются высота и ширина здесь?
Потому что в принципе получилось,но нужно сделать отступы,чтобы фигура находилась по середине

Comment: Ну так это уже другой вопрос. И за расположение вашей кнопки отвечает не она сама, а layout, в котором она располагается.

Comment: Команда     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" не помогает в Layout

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60580/discussion-between-shcherbuk-and-vladimir-parfenov).